# Count characters before some string iOS

Tags: ios, string, loops, character

I need to count characters in string before some string and after some string. For example, I have string "**This is example string**" and I need to know howmany characters are before word "example" (it is 8 chars in this case) and how many characters are after word "example" (7 in that case...). My idea was to loop that string and count every character, but how to stop it before that requied word? Thanks for every idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

```
NSString *sample = @"This is example string";
NSRange b = [sample rangeOfString:@"example"];

if (b.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"%d characters before", b.location);
    NSLog(@"%d characters after", [sample length] - b.location - b.length);
}
```

Comment: So, characters before is `b.location`. Characters after is `[sample length] - b.location - b.length` (but obviously, first make sure `b.location != NSNotFound`).